# How can I get code syntax highlighting in Google Docs for Work?

Tags: google-apps

I am interested about a code syntax highlighting plugin that is safe to be enabled and used on the enterprise version: Google Apps for Work.

When using the enterprise version admins needs to manually enable some plugins after they are verified to be safe for corporate use.

Is one of code pretifier plugins safe for corporate use? -- I guess one condition would be not to send the code to a third party server.